# How to equalise two charts C#

Tags: c#, charts, datasource

I want to pass a chart from one WinForm to another as parameter.
How can I equalise the data of thoose charts?
I want something like this:

```
chart1.DataSource=chart2.DataSource;
```

Comment: What are these variables? (what type) - How do you assign chart1's datasource in the first place?

Comment: In the first place, I populate the chart from an array, but I think that it has to exist a method to equalise the data between two charts.

Comment: Yes, there is: `chart1.DataSource = myArray; chart2.DataSource = myArray;`

Comment: Why pass the whole chart?  Why not just pass the data?

Comment: Because the chart has a properties that i would like to copy also

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: no mi friend, not yet :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
chart1.DataSource = chart2.DataSource;
```

just fine. But it will not be enough.

You also need to add any code needed for the data binding, e.g. setting up the `ValueMembers` and maybe `ValueTypes`.:

```
Series s1 = chart1.Series[0];
Series s2 = chart2.Series[0];

s2.XValueMember  = s1.XValueMember;
s2.XValueType    = s1.XValueType;
s2.YValueMembers = s1.YValueMembers;
..
```

..or whatever you need.

And, if you want to copy **other** properties as well, well, of course you need to set them **as well**..:

```
chart2.BackColor = chart1.BackColor;
```

You could use reflection to find and copy all properties, but imo this is overkill. I would write a function that takes the two Charts as params and does the whole cloning..